# Third axiom of Kolmogorov axioms

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, infinity

Let us define for a countably infinite set $S$ of real numbers that can be enumerated as $x_1,x_2,\cdots$,

$$P(S) = \sum_{x \in S}p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty p(x_i) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i),$$

if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty p(x_i)$ converges absolutely. Suppose we are only given
$$P(\Omega) = 1$$
for a countably infinite set $\Omega$ and $p(l) \geq 0$ for all $l \in \Omega$. Is it true that for any countable sequence $E_1, E_2, \cdots$ of disjoint subsets of $\Omega$, we must have

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(E_i)$$

? This is the third axiom of the Kolmogorov axioms but I'm wondering if we can "replace" it with the given condition above for discrete probability spaces. I managed to only show this for a finite sequence of disjoint subsets by induction.

Answer (score 0):

This  fails for the infinite case. Consider the following $P$ $$P(A) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{If $A$ is finite}\\
1 & \text{If $A$ is infinite}\end{cases} $$

then consider $P$ defined on the subsets of $\Bbb{N}$.

you can see that $\Bbb{N} = \cup_{n} \{n\}$ but 
 $$1 = P(\Bbb{N}) = P(\cup_{n} \{n\}) \neq \sum_n P(\{n\}) = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega$ be any set and $p:\Omega\to[0,1]$.
For any subset $A\subseteq \Omega$  define 
 $$P(A)=\sup\left\{\sum_{x\in F}p(x): F\subseteq A, F\mbox{ is finite}\right\}.$$

**Exercise:** If $P(\Omega)=1$, then $P$ defines a probability measure on
the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $\Omega.$

Is this your question? If so, let me know where you get stuck
 and I'll try to help.